# step issue -There is a nav element with an aria-label of Main Site Links

Tags: html, css

I am new to aria-label and it is doing my head in! Please I need help to resolve this step to complete my task.I'm currently creating my personal homepage. Thanking You!

The step: × FAIL There is a nav element with an aria-label of Main Site Links.

```
<header class="c-site-header">
    <nav id="aria-label"> 
        <a class="main site links" href="#">About Me</a> 
        <a class="main site links" href="my project">My Projects</a> 
        <a class="main site links" href="contact me">Contact Me</a> 
    </nav>
    <h1>Welcome To My Page</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant portion of the code? Your question is not clear enough as it stands.

Details on usage of aria-label can be seen here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label

Comment: <header class="c-site-header">
  <nav id="aria-label">
    <a class="main site links" href="#">About Me</a>
    <a class="main site links" href="my project">My Projects</a>
    <a class="main site links" href="contact me">Contact Me</a>
  </nav>
    <h1>Welcome To My Page</h1>
   
  </header>

Comment: @ToinAjayi - I have done it for you.  In future, please edit you post to add additional information.

Comment: Noted, thanks Rohit. I am new and still learning how the platform works. However,I still need help on  how to implement the aria-label to my page.

Comment: Thank you Lawrence_monk. I've read the docs attached to your response but I'm still lost as to how to implement the aria-label to my webpage.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so your intended usage of `aria-label` in your code (see below) is a bit muddled.

Your code:

```html
<header class="c-site-header">
    <nav id="aria-label"> 
        <a class="main site links" href="#">About Me</a> 
        <a class="main site links" href="my project">My Projects</a> 
        <a class="main site links" href="contact me">Contact Me</a> 
    </nav>
    <h1>Welcome To My Page</h1>
</header>
```

`aria-label`, is itself a property which sits on HTML elements (not as an ID) and should only be used where text that could label an element is not visible.

**Consider this example:**
You have an SVG of a 'close' icon. The browser can only see that you have an SVG, it cannot determine its contents or purpose. To those who can see it, it might be readily obvious what it is, but for those with an impairment who rely on assistive technology, you need to provide additional information.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 371.23 371.23" style="enable-background:new 0 0 371.23 371.23"...>
```

The additional information you add can be done in many ways, one of which is the `aria-label`:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-label="Close the mobile menu" viewBox="0 0 371.23 371.23" style="enable-background:new 0 0 371.23 371.23"...>
```

Now assistive technologies can use the label to explain what this element does.

In your context, you are using HTML5 tags which have implied details and you have no need to add additional aria information.

For more details about aria, it's usage and constraints, I recommend [MDN's documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label)